# django + uwsgi + ngnix = Django CSRF verification error

Tags: django

I have a simple application that allows you to upload images onto the server  and it is set up on my production server which consist of of django + uwsgi + ngnix . Now the problem is the csrf token doesn't appear in the template and when I try to upload an image it display this error

```
Forbidden (403)

CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
Reason given for failure:
CSRF token missing or incorrect.
```

I understand this error clearly . `{% csrf_token %}` is inside the template and the csrf is enabled on `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` . I also tested my application on development server and it works fine . What can cause the `{% csrf_token %}` to not appear in the template on my production server.

I can see the form but when I view the source there is no csrf token.

settings

```
DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': '/home/projects/mysite/d.db',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        # The following settings are not used with sqlite3:
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',                      # Empty for localhost through domain sockets or '127.0.0.1' for localhost through TCP.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default.
    }
}


ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1


U    SE_I18N = True


USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/projects/mysite/media/'


MEDIA_URL = '/media/'


STATIC_ROOT = ''

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

ist of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#         'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'


# Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)
```

views

```
def upload(request):
    form = ImageForm()
    if request.POST:
        form = ImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        image = request.FILES.get('image')
        CarPhoto.objects.create(user=request.user,cars=1,description='dwq',image=image)
    return render(request,'image.html',{'form':form})
```

template

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

{% csrf_token %}
<div id="c">image</div> {{form.image}}
dwqdwqdwq
        <input type = "submit" value= "add" id="box2"/>
</form>{% csrf_token %}
```

view source

```
 <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"><div id="c">image</div><input    id="id_image" name="image" type="file" /> dwqdwqdwq <input type="submit" value="add" id="box2"/></form>
```

Comment: What version of Django?

Comment: @limelights django 1.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your view is missing the token since you're not setting it.

Change this line

```
return render(request,'image.html',{'form':form})
```

to

```
context = {'form':form,}
context.update(csrf(request))
return render(request,'image.html', context)
```

or

```
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

return render_to_response('image.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

You can use either depending on your flavor, also, you have to `{% csrf_token %}`s in your template. The one outside of the `<form>` is redundant.

[Reading the docs is good!](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/csrf/#how-to-use-it)

Comment: What does it say when you `print context`?

Comment: I have no idea , what do you think about the settings?

Comment: limelights what do you mean via print context? replace return for context?

Comment: no just `print context`. Also try to add this to your form `action="."`.

Comment: I placed print context above return and it gave me the error 502 Bad Gateway

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32406/discussion-between-limelights-and-uncle-toby)

Comment: limelights , may you help me on something , please limelights :)

Comment: Yeah, sure, go into the chat.

Comment: if you have spare time , could you help me out for lil bit